# How to close a blank screen

Tags: unity, session

I tried to install bspwm to my ubuntu, when I restarted my computer, I logged in with bspwm session, the bad thing is, no keybindings work and I cannot open the session screen again, how can I close bspwm and open the unity and fix the problem ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you have a look at [troubleshooting section](https://github.com/windelicato/dotfiles/wiki/bspwm-for-dummies#help-i-get-a-blank-screen-and-my-keybindings-dont-work)?
Taken from their troubleshooting site:

> There are a few ways to debug this. First, a blank screen is good.
>   That means bspwm is running (usually).
>
> I would confirm that your xinitrc looks something like
>
> ```
> sxhkd & 
> exec bspwm
> ```
>
> The ampersand is important. Next, try spawning a
>   terminal in your xinitrc to see if its getting positioned properly. It
>   should appear somewhat "centered" on the screen. To do this, use this
>   .xinitrc:
>
> ```
> sxhkd & 
> urxvt & 
> exec bspwm
> ```
>
> If nothing shows up, that means you
>   probably forgot to install urxvt. If it shows up but isn't centered or
>   taking up most of your screen, that means BSPWM isn't starting
>   properly. Make sure that you've chmod +x ~/.config/bspwm/bspwmrc.
>
> Next, type pidof sxhkd in that terminal you spawned. It should return
>   a process number. If it doesn't, that means sxhd isn't running. Try to
>   be explicit and run sxhkd -c ~/.config/sxhkd/sxhkdrc. You could also
>   try changing the Super key to something like Alt in your sxhkdrc and
>   see if that helps. Another common problem is copying the text from the
>   example files instead of physically copying the file over. Copying /
>   pasting code usually leads to indentation issues which sxhkd can be
>   sensitive to.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I tried all of it and none of them have worked :(

Comment: I could not interact with the screen at all, I tried to login with CTRL + ALT + 3, 1, 2 - than, i removed the file of pswm, after that, ubuntu login page opened, than I selected unity

Comment: Why dont you create another question? Probably somebody can help you out!

Comment: You are very welcome! I am sorry that I could not help you more.